# How do I get min/avg/var rtt for all TCP connections in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I'm trying to implement a software that tracks open TCP connections and classify them based on TCP round trip time estimates, on Linux. I'm looking for similar information that the program nettop shows on MacOS X.

```
$ nettop -m tcp
```

It shows a list of open connections by the process that owns them. It includes the current round trip time min, mean and variance estimates for each connection.

For listening to a program's own connections it could be done something like in  http://linuxgazette.net/136/pfeiffer.html but I'm looking for something like nettop that shows the information for all connections on the machine. On OS X that does not require root  access but it is fine if the answer does.

I'd prefer a Python compatible version but if not available, I can live with C. If there is an existing command-line utility like nettop for Linux, that's also interesting.

Related:

- Wikipedia: Karn's algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Some of this information is available in the command:

```
ss -i -t
```

Comment: Importantly I don't see connection rtt estimate information. Can you derive it from information shown? E.g. "rto:0.23 ato:0.04 cwnd:10 qack:15"? How?

Comment: These days ss will now show the **rtt/rttvar**, **mss** and other parameters, to get extended info add the `-e` command line option to ss, which shows things like TCP options e.g SACK

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with your own code you can look at the output of libpcap or tcpdump and compare the timestamp on packets with corresponding sequence and ack numbers and average those out for the last few seconds.

- 12:19:39.331248 IP 10.0.60.243.ssh > 192.168.50.22.21950: P **11952**:12180(228)
- 12:19:39.331388 IP 10.0.60.243.ssh > 192.168.50.22.21950: P **12328**:12476(148)
- 12:19:39.380981 IP 192.168.50.22.21950 > 10.0.60.243.ssh: . ack **11952** win 65535
- 12:19:39.381039 IP 10.0.60.243.ssh > 192.168.50.22.21950: P **12624**:12772(148)
- 12:19:39.381054 IP 192.168.50.22.21950 > 10.0.60.243.ssh: . ack **12328** win 65159
- 12:19:39.381058 IP 192.168.50.22.21950 > 10.0.60.243.ssh: . ack **12624** win 64863

This would average out to about 50ms rtt

Comment: That's a pretty resource-intensive approach assuming there's more than a couple of connections. I hope there's a way to get it from the TCP stack more directly.

Comment: I couldn't find the source for nettop but I did find the CVS for jnettop which is supposed to be similar. http://jnettop.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jnettop/jnettop/

Comment: The key for me is the rtt, not active connections. lsof can show active connections. Traffic amounts are also no interest to me.